# Series- combining similar terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm confused about the grouping of terms in a series- I know that sometimes based on grouping of terms, a series can converge where ungrouped, it would actually diverge. 
So then, when can I combine terms in a series?

IE is: Σ$a_{n}$ for the two definitions equal or different?

$a_{n}=2\sqrt{2+n} - \sqrt{2n} - \sqrt{2+n}$

$a_{n}=\sqrt{2+n} - \sqrt{2n} $

I saw a number of similar questions but could not find an answer, if there is one please link!

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the $n^{th}$ term $a_n = \dfrac{2-n}{\sqrt{2+n} + \sqrt{2n}}\sim c\sqrt{n} , c \neq 0$, and the latter does not converge to $0$, hence the series $\sum a_n$ diverges.

**Note:** The two series are the same and both diverge. Also, in this case and in general, grouping cannot be done as at least one of them diverges. Grouping can be done if both of them converge.

You can easily prove that if $\sum a_n, \sum b_n$ converge then $\sum (a_n+b_n)$ also converges.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I know that the series diverges I'm asking of the two series are the same and if in general, terms can be grouped.

Comment: Just to clarify, so if I can prove that the second series diverges, then I it is true that this is the same as the first series? Or is it that if I can prove the second series diverges, I can conclude that the first also diverges.

Comment: @jacksonf: Both of them are the same and they both converge or diverge. My last statement says that if you can write $a_n = b_n + c_n$, and further $\sum b_n, \sum c_n$ converge, then $\sum a_n$ converges.